# ExpressJS - Sequelize - Tipo de dados não reconhecido

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize-js

Criei manualmente um banco de dados sql e agora estou tentando configurar meus modelos de sequenciamento para corresponder às colunas em minhas tabelas sql, mas encontrei um problema com meu modelo relacionado a um tipo de campo não reconhecido. Não consigo identificar o erro e se ele está relacionado a não corresponder ao tipo de dados de um campo no meu banco de dados ou se a sequência não reconhece parte do meu código.

este é o erro:

```
C:\Users\Fabricio\Desktop\programação\node- 
pratica\project1\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model
.js:1005
    throw new Error(`Unrecognized datatype for attribute 
"${this.name}.${name}"`);
    ^

Error: Unrecognized datatype for attribute "postagens.titulo"
at rawAttributes._.mapValues 
(C:\Users\Fabricio\Desktop\programação\node-pratica\project
1\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1005:15)
at C:\Users\Fabricio\Desktop\programação\node- 
pratica\project1\node_modules\lodash\lodas
h.js:13401:38
at C:\Users\Fabricio\Desktop\programação\node- 
pratica\project1\node_modules\lodash\lodas
h.js:4905:15
at baseForOwn (C:\Users\Fabricio\Desktop\programação\node- 
pratica\project1\node_modules\
lodash\lodash.js:2990:24)
at Function.mapValues (C:\Users\Fabricio\Desktop\programação\node- 
pratica\project1\node_
modules\lodash\lodash.js:13400:7)
at Function.init (C:\Users\Fabricio\Desktop\programação\node- 
pratica\project1\node_modul
es\sequelize\lib\model.js:1001:28)
at Sequelize.define (C:\Users\Fabricio\Desktop\programação\node- 
pratica\project1\node_mo
dules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:426:11)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Fabricio\Desktop\programação\node- 
pratica\project1\model
s\post.js:3:27)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Este é o meu código:

```
const db = require('./db')

const Post = db.sequelize.define('postagens', {
titulo: {
    type: db.Sequelize.string 
},
conteudo: {
    type: db.Sequelize.text
}
})

module.exports = Post

Post.sync({force:true})
```

modulo 'db':

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')

// Conexão com o banco de dados

const sequelize = new Sequelize('postapp', 'root', 'frajola10', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'mysql'
})

// Exportar o modulo

module.exports = {
    Sequelize: Sequelize,
    sequelize: sequelize
}
```

arquivo 'index.js':

```
// Chamada dos modulos da aplicação

const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

// Config

// Template Engine

    app.engine('handlebars', handlebars({defaultLayout: 'main'}))
    app.set('view engine', 'handlebars')

// Body Parser

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
    app.use(bodyParser.json())

// Rotas

// '.get' cria uma rota do tipo get

app.get('/cad', function(req,res){

// 'render' renderiza o arquivo handlebars dentro da pasta views('form')

    res.render('form')
})

// '.post' cria uma rota do tipo post

app.post('/add', function(req,res){

// 'req' faz uma requisão do conteudo do post presente no local 
// indicado(body.titulo)

    res.send('texto: ' + req.body.titulo + '<br>' + ' conteudo: ' + 
    req.body.conteudo)
 })

// Criação do servidor local

  app.listen(8080, function(){
  console.log('Rodando!!')
  })
```

formulário handlebars 'form.handlebars':

```
<form action="/add" method="post">
   <p>Titulo</p>
   <input type="text" name="titulo">
   <p>Conteudo</p>
   <textarea name="conteudo"></textarea>
   <br>
   <button>Cadastrar</button>
</form>
```

arquivo 'main.handlebars':

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    {{{body}}}
</body>
</html>
```

Poderiam me responder oque esta acontecendo?

Comment: Cara só com isso que postou não tem como saber, posta o Html do form que envia os dados e o arquivo Js que gerencia o post.

Comment: Deu na mesma, sem o html do form e o js que contem as rotas e o que deve acontecer quando do acesso a cada rota não tem como ninguém saber o que está acontecendo!

Comment: É, se seu código no **index.js** for só isso mesmo, não tem como dar certo mesmo, não tem nenhum método **`create()`** ou **`update()`** ligando o model ao Html.

Comment: eu ja possuo um banco de dados criado

Comment: Vc tem um banco, tem a conexão com o banco e tem um model, só não ta fazendo nada com o model, ta faltando ligar os elementos html **(input de titulo e conteudo)** com o banco através do model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, 'Post.js':

```
const db = require('./db')

const Post = db. sequelize.define('postagens', { 
titulo: {
    type: db.Sequelize.STRING
    },
    conteudo:{
     type: db.Sequelize.TEXT}
    })

Post.sync({force:true})
```